# Tax situation for UK citizen working remotely in France but getting paid in GBP by a UK employer

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, eur-euro, france, gbp-british-pound

I am a UK [and Australian] citizen. I have only lived in the UK for 9 months since Nov 2004.  Apart from the 9 months in 2014, i have lived in the US for the last 7 years working for the same employer.

I'm investigating the possibility of living in France [Spain or Italy are contenders too] but still working for my current employer, via the branch located in London, and getting paid in GBP.

Can anyone advise me on what the tax situation would be. i would either be employed as a PAYE employee or as a contractor. I understand the UK has a double taxation treaty with France so i assume that i would be taxed ONLY in France based on the total income of the household [just my family - wife and 2 kids].

Are there any issues that i should be aware of with getting paid in one currency [GBP] and taxed in a different country based on another [EUR]?

would i have to declare my earnings in my UK tax return going forward or just the French return..?

thanks in advance for any help

Wes

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income)

**You may need to pay UK Income Tax on your foreign income, eg:**

- wages if you work abroad
- foreign investments and savings interest
- rental income on overseas property
- income from pensions held overseas
- Foreign income is anything from outside England, Scotland, Wales and Northern  Ireland. The Channel Islands and the Isle of Man are classed as foreign.

> Residents normally pay UK tax on all their income, whether it’s from the UK or abroad. But there are special rules for UK residents whose permanent home (‘domicile’) is abroad.

**Work out your residence status**

> Whether you’re UK resident usually depends on how many days you spend in the UK in the tax year (6 April to 5 April the following year).**
>
> You’re automatically resident if either:

- you spent 183 or more days in the UK in the tax year
- your only home was in the UK - you must have owned, rented or lived in it for at least 91 days in total - and you spent at least 30 days there in the tax year

> You’re automatically non-resident if either:

- you spent less than 16 days in the UK (or 46 days if you haven’t been classed as UK resident for the 3 previous tax years)
- you work abroad full-time (averaging at least 35 hours a week) and spent less than 91 days in the UK, of which less than 31 days were spent working